# Manipulating x,y,z coordinate data set to be from origin's point of view in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math

## Changing The Origin of A Data Set

I have a data set in x,y,z coordinates that represents the position and velocity of an object approaching the origin (0,0,0) from the object's point of view. I am trying to manipulate the data set so that it represents the same motion but from the origin's point of view instead.

I've tried to flip the entire data set using data = data(end:-1:1,:) and multiplying this data set by negative 1. This makes some sense in my head but I'm not confident in this solution. The data set is so large that its not really viable for me to check my results by hand but I believe the math should be straightforward enough. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is very clear. What do you mean "objects point of view"? If the object was approaching from the x-axis only, directly towards 0,0,0, what would you want data to be? Isn't it as it is, exactly what you want it to be?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Think of it like this: the object starts at point A represented by (Ax,Ay,Az) and the origin lies at point O represented by (Ox,Oy,Oz). The data set currently returns the position of the object in relation to point A where A is viewed as a local origin (0,0,0). In my case, this ends up with with a final data point of (+,-,-). I am trying to manipulate the data such that the final data point is (0,0,0) and the data set reflects an object approaching this value starting from position A.

Comment: @AnderBiguri To answer your question, if the object starts at point (2,0,0) (which it views as the origin) The initial data set would be: t1: (0,0,0) t2: (-1,0,0) t3: (-2,0,0) and I would want it to instead be t1: (2,0,0) t2: (1,0,0) t3: (0,0,0). This is where I got my original method, I am just unsure if this is also the correct way to manipulate the velocity.

Comment: Yes, changes of reference points are done by just subtracting the new origin to the data. your intuition was correct, this is part of fundamental maths.  I am voting to close the question because its about fundamentals of mathematics, not programming.

Comment: @AnderBiguri The reason I asked it here is because my data set is in the form of x,y,z,xV,yV,zV and I wasn't sure if I could accomplish my goal with a single operation on the entire data set.

Comment: Mathematical operations and fundamentals don't change with respect to how many times you use them. Its the same moving 1 vector or infinite vectors.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, I understand that. The data set contains both position and velocity values. I cannot simply subtract the new origin from the velocity values.

Comment: The velocity doesn't change, no. Is that your confusion? You are changing the reference frame, so you can shift everything, but the velocity won't change. Something going up at X speed won't change that its going up at X speed regardless where you are looking it from. It may be on your right or on your left, but won't change speed. So you don't need to touch the vectors to change the reference frame,  Again, this is fundamentals of mathematics and vectors, not programming.

Comment: @AnderBiguri In this case, the distinction between speed and velocity is important. I think you did just lead me in the correct direction though. I believe that if I subtract the new origin from the position vectors and multiply the velocity vectors by -1 I will correctly change the data set.

Comment: Speed is simply the norm of the velocity vector. Does not change w.r.t. reference frame (unless you are doing speed of light stuff).